# how to deduce current time (Clock) from unix gettime Jan 1970 API?

Tags: c, time

I am using the `time()` function which returns the number of seconds passed since jan 1970;
I want to deduce the current time and Date , here is what i have seen..

```
   #define SECONDS_PER_YEAR  31536000u
   #define SECONDS_PER_MONTH 2628288u
    #define SECONDS_PER_WEEK  604800u
```

...

```
       time_t unaccountedSeconds = time(NULL);

        // Calculate years
          int years = unaccountedSeconds / SECONDS_PER_YEAR;
           // Seconds not absorbed by years
                    unaccountedSeconds = unaccountedSeconds % SECONDS_PER_YEAR;

      // Calculate months
           int months = unaccountedSeconds / SECONDS_PER_MONTH;
                 // Seconds not absorbed by months
         unaccountedSeconds = unaccountedSeconds % SECONDS_PER_MONTH;

              // Calculate weeks
```

that didn't work for me.

Comment: That should work, if all months were the same length.  But they're not.  (Nor are all years, for that matter.)

Comment: Hint:  Divide by the number of seconds in 4 years.  And convert the remainder into days and seconds within the day, before you try to figure out month/day.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the localtime(3) function. That does the breakdown for you, and gives you a filled struct tm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm* tmTime = localtime(&now);

int years = tmTime.tm_year;
int months = tmTime.tm_mon;
int wDay = tmTime.tm_wday; // day of the week
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

man -a time

man -a asctime

man -a localtime

```
result = time(NULL);
printf("current time %s  its %ju secs since the Epoch\n", 
             asctime(localtime(&result)), (uintmax_t)result);
return(0);
```